# How to configure the use of BIRT libraries within a Maven webapp project?

Tags: maven, web-applications, birt

I am setting up a web project using Maven. In the project I want to use BIRT reports. Each report uses a BIRT library. I use the BirtEngine to generate PDFs on demand using the the `rptdesign`s.

When I test the project, the library is not found. The logging indicates that the app is expecting the library at `/src/main/webapps/birt/mylib.rptlibrary` which, at runtime, is false.

I edited the report and changed the path to simply `mylib.rptlibrary` and that seems to solve the problem.

Did I do something wrong? Should I configure the project (Maven, web.xml) differently?